# Remove previously selected dropdown items

Tags: javascript, forms, drop-down-menu

I have a form that asks people to order something, lets just say "Red", "Blue", and "Green."  Next to each color is a dropdown with the available order "1", "2", or "3".

If someone selects "2" for Red, I want to remove that option for the other colors that haven't been selected yet.

I'm not sure where to start.  I am novice and have really only used HTML, CSS, and PHP although I have some javascript/jquery experience.

I'm messing around with the code below but need the "onchange" function to affect the SECOND dropdown and not the first...

```js
function myFunction1() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
  x.remove(x.selectedIndex);
}
```

```html
<form>
  Select a fruit:
  <br>
  <select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction1()">
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Pear</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
  </select>
    <select id="mySelect2">
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Pear</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br>
```

Comment: Please share what you have already tried.

Comment: _not sure where to start_ - try something. Start with the HTML. Then look up how to do javascript when a select item is chosen. Then look up how to change other select items from javascript. -- Even if it fails miserably, it's important that you put an attempt together with how you think it should work. That allows others to see where you're having trouble and comment directly on that.

Comment: I'll do some more digging and see what I can come up with.  I was completely at a zero as to how to even begin.  Could I create a javascript array and then pull each item out as it is selected or something?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are expecting:

```js
function removeSelectedNumber() {
  var x = document.getElementById("numberSelect");
  x.remove(x.selectedIndex);
}
```

```html
<form>
  Select a fruit:
  <br>
  <select id="colorSelect">
    <option>Red</option>
    <option>Green</option>
    <option>Blue</option>
    <option>Yellow</option>
  </select>
  <select id="numberSelect" onchange="removeSelectedNumber()">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br>
```